# QGIS syntax raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm working with QGIS and I want to reclassify a raster in different ranges.

Using the following statement does not work even recognized as valid

```
(2950 <= "dem_tallat @ 1"> = 3050) = 3000
```

Where I can find a document that shows the syntax to use for Raster Calculator?

Comment: try this one `(2950 <= "dem_tallat@1" <= 3050) = 3000` - you obviously used wrong comparison sign

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of sources with examples showing what syntax can be used for rasters. Basically, common mathematical logics are used such as:

- Mathematical (+, -, *, /)
- Trigonometric (sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan)
- Comparison (<, >, =, <=, >=)
- Logical (AND, OR)

[Here](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/) you can find how some of those syntax are used in some examples.

Other sources can be found in the QGIS documentation:

- http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html
- http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/no_data.html

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I don't find any expression to satisfy my purpose. To recognise a range of values and transform this in another value

Comment: Have you tried what @SS_Rebelious suggested?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't works...

Answer (score 1):

To map values from `(2950-3050)` into `3000` and preserving other values of `dem_tallat` :

```
(2950 <= "dem_tallat@1" AND  "dem_tallat@1" <= 3050)*3000 + (2950 > "dem_tallat@1" OR  "dem_tallat@1" > 3050)*"dem_tallat@1"
```